# print pdf of filtered data only in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pdf

I am creating a report of users in which I use different type of filters but how can I get pdf of filtered data only .I use,

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
```

my controller

```
function pdf()
    {
     $pdf = \App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
     $pdf->loadHTML($this->convert_customer_data_to_html());
     return $pdf->stream();
    }
```

but in above code I get all data from database, but my basic view have different type of filters like that
1-select from option

```
<div class="col-md-3 p-0" style="margin-bottom:35px">
          <select class="select-items" id="report_type">
            <option value="rider">user</option>
            <option value="driver">Driver</option>
          </select>
        </div>
```

2-autocomplete

```
<div class="col-md-3 p-0" style="margin-bottom:35px">
            <input type="text" id="myInput" onchange="SearchName()" onkeyup="SearchName()">
            <div id="List"></div>
          </div>
```

3-another dropdown like no 1

all the filters are working good on view ,but my question is that how will I get pdf of filtered data only

Comment: so by this you mean that the option you selected in html, should be visible in pdf as well

Comment: no, I just want that after filters only current data of table go to pdf page

Comment: you can use a pdf preview allow users to select values from the form, then use a button named export as pdf, submit the data from your preview as a form to the controller & then use the view with given data from form to generate a pdf